# Javascript to PHP function not returning the same results

Tags: javascript, php, function

I have two function here written in javascript that increments/decrements numbers. I need to have those functions written in PHP (and I am not good at PHP at all). The problem I have is that in PHP all the values returned by the functions `inc()` and `dec()` are 0.

Here is the JS:

```
function getInc(num) {
    let abs = Math.abs(num);
    if ((Math.log10(abs) % 1 === 0) && (num < 0)) return num / 10;
    let inc = Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(abs)));
    if (abs === num) return inc;
    return -inc;
}
function inc(num) {
    if ((num === 0) || (typeof num != 'number')) { return 0 }
    if ((num < -1) && (num >= -10)) {
        return Math.floor(Math.round(num) - getInc(num))
    }
    if ((num < 0) && (num >= -1)) {
        const result = num - getInc(num);
        return Math.floor(parseFloat(result / getInc(num)).toPrecision(12)) * getInc(num)
    }
    if (num >= 1 && num < 10) {
        return Math.round(Math.floor(num + getInc(num)));
    }
    if ((num >= 10) || (num > 0 && num < 1)) {
        const result = Math.ceil(num / getInc(num)) * getInc(num);
        if (result === num) { return num + getInc(num) }
        else { return result }
    }
    if (num <= -20) {
        const result = -Math.ceil(num / -getInc(num)) * getInc(num) - getInc(num);
        if (result === num) { return num + getInc(num) }
        else { return result }
    }
    if (num < -10 && num > -20) {
        return -9
    }
}

function getDec(num) {
    let abs = Math.abs(num);
    if ((Math.log10(abs) % 1 === 0) && (num > 0)) return num / 10;
    let inc = Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(abs)));
    if (abs === num) return inc;
    return -inc;
}

function dec(num) {
    if ((num === 0) || (typeof num != 'number')) { return 0 }
    if ((num < -1) && (num > -10)) {
    }
    if ((num < 0) && (num >= -1)) {
        const result = num + getDec(num);
        return Math.floor(parseFloat(result / getDec(num)).toPrecision(12)) * getDec(num)
    }
    if (num > 1 && num < 10) {
        return Math.round(Math.floor(num - getDec(num)));
    }
    if ((num >= 20) || (num > 0 && num <= 1)) {
        const result = Math.floor(parseFloat(num / getDec(num)).toPrecision(12)) * getDec(num) - getDec(num);
        if (result === num) { return num - getDec(num) }
        else { return result }
    }
    if (num >= 10 && num < 20) {
        return 9
    }
    if (num <= -10) {
        const result = -(Math.ceil(num / -getDec(num)) * getDec(num) - getDec(num));
        if (result === num) { return num - getDec(num) }
        else { return result }
    }
}
```

And here is the PHP:

```
<?php
function getInc( $num ) {
    $abs = abs( $num );
    if ( ( log10( $abs ) % 1 === 0 ) && ( $num < 0 ) ) { return $num / 10;  }
    $inc = pow( 10, floor( log10( $abs ) ) );
    if ( $abs === $num ) { return $inc;  }
    return -$inc;
}
function inc( $num ) {
    if ( ( $num === 0 ) || ( gettype( $num ) != 'number' ) ) { return 0;  }
    if ( ( $num < -1 ) && ( $num >= -10 ) ) {
        return floor( round( $num ) - getInc( $num ) );
    }
    if ( ( $num < 0 ) && ( $num >= -1 ) ) {
        $result = $num - getInc( $num );
        return floor( floatval( $result / getInc( $num ) )->toPrecision( 12 ) ) * getInc( $num );
    }
    if ( $num >= 1 && $num < 10 ) {
        return round( floor( $num + getInc( $num ) ) );
    }
    if ( ( $num >= 10 ) || ( $num > 0 && $num < 1 ) ) {
        $result = ceil( $num / getInc( $num ) ) * getInc( $num );
        if ( $result === $num ) { return $num + getInc( $num );  } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }
    if ( $num <= -20 ) {
        $result = -ceil( $num / -getInc( $num ) ) * getInc( $num ) - getInc( $num );
        if ( $result === $num ) { return $num + getInc( $num );  } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }
    if ( $num < -10 && $num > -20 ) {
        return -9;
    }
}

function getDec( $num ) {
    $abs = abs( $num );
    if ( ( log10( $abs ) % 1 === 0 ) && ( $num > 0 ) ) { return $num / 10;  }
    $inc = pow( 10, floor( log10( $abs ) ) );
    if ( $abs === $num ) { return $inc;  }
    return -$inc;
}

function dec( $num ) {
    if ( ( $num === 0 ) || ( gettype( $num ) != 'number' ) ) { return 0;  }
    if ( ( $num < -1 ) && ( $num > -10 ) ) {
    }
    if ( ( $num < 0 ) && ( $num >= -1 ) ) {
        $result = $num + getDec( $num );
        return floor( $result / getDec( $num ) ) * getDec( $num );
    }
    if ( $num > 1 && $num < 10 ) {
        return round( floor( $num - getDec( $num ) ) );
    }
    if ( ( $num >= 20 ) || ( $num > 0 && $num <= 1 ) ) {
        $result = floor($num / getDec( $num ) ) * getDec( $num ) - getDec( $num );
        if ( $result === $num ) { return $num - getDec( $num );  } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }
    if ( $num >= 10 && $num < 20 ) {
        return 9;
    }
    if ( $num <= -10 ) {
        $result = -( ceil( $num / -getDec( $num ) ) * getDec( $num ) - getDec( $num ) );
        if ( $result === $num ) { return $num - getDec( $num );  } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

Do you see where is this issue coming from? Thank you in advance!

Edited PHP:

```
<?php
function getInc($num) {
    $abs = abs($num);
    $inc = pow(10, floor(log10($abs)));
    if ($abs === $num) { return $inc;  }
    return -$inc;
}
function inc($num) {
    if (($num === 0) || !is_numeric($num) || is_string($num)) { return 0;  }
    if (($num < -1) && ($num >= -10)) {
        return round(round($num) - getInc($num));
    }
    if (($num < 0) && ($num >= -1)) {
        $result = $num - getInc($num);
        return round(floatval($result / getInc($num))) * getInc($num);
    }
    if ($num >= 1 && $num < 10) {
        return round(round($num + getInc($num)));
    }
    if (($num >= 10) || ($num > 0 && $num < 1)) {
        $result = ceil($num / getInc($num)) * getInc($num);
        if ($result === $num) { return $num + getInc($num);  } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }
    if ($num <= -20) {
        $result = -ceil($num / -getInc($num)) * getInc($num) - getInc($num);
        if ($result === $num) { return $num + getInc($num);  } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }
    if ($num < -10 && $num > -20) {
        return -9;
    }
}

function getDec($num) {
    $abs = abs($num);
    $inc = pow(10, floor(log10($abs)));
    if ($abs === $num) { return $inc;  }
    return -$inc;
}

function dec($num) {
    if (($num === 0) || !is_numeric($num) || is_string($num)) { return 0; }
    if (($num < -1) && ($num > -10)) {
    }
    if (($num < 0) && ($num >= -1)) {
        $result = $num + getDec($num);
        return round($result / getDec($num)) * getDec($num);
    }
    if ($num > 1 && $num < 10) {
        return round(round($num - getDec($num)));
    }
    if (($num >= 20) || ($num > 0 && $num <= 1)) {
        $result = round($num / getDec($num)) * getDec($num) - getDec($num);
        if ($result === $num) { return $num - getDec($num);  } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }
    if ($num >= 10 && $num < 20) {
        return 9;
    }
    if ($num <= -10) {
        $result = -(ceil($num / -getDec($num)) * getDec($num) - getDec($num));
        if ($result === $num) { return $num - getDec($num);  } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: JS `%` is a floating point function. PHP `%` is a integer function. Replace it by function `fmod()`  to get floating functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

[`gettype`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php) returns **integer** or **double** for numbers.

To test a numeric variable, you can use `is_numeric($num)`.

To filter numeric string, you can use `is_numeric($num) && !is_string($num)`.

Answer (score 0):

One error I see is that inside of `inc()` you are trying to call a class method on a float here:

```
    return floor(floatval($result / getInc($num))->toPrecision(12)) * getInc($num);
```

`floor()` returns a float (even though it's rounded down to the lowest integer number) as described in the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php). You can't call a function/method on a float in PHP as you can in JavaScript.

You can try to use [`round()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) like this instead:

```
    return round(floatval($result / getInc($num)),12) * getInc($num);
```

As for why inc() and dec() are returning 0, the first line of both functions check for number by doing this:

```
  if (($num === 0) || (gettype($num) != 'number')) {
```

`gettype()` doesn't return a type of 'number'. In JavaScript integers and floats are all considered of type number but in PHP they are separate. You can use 'is_numeric()` instead.

```
  if (($num === 0) || !is_numeric($num)) {
```

That will check for strings that look like numbers as well so if you don't want numeric strings, you can do another check to filter those out. You could use `is_string()` for that.

```
  if (($num === 0) || !is_numeric($num) || is_string($num)) {
```

----------Edited after getting some test numbers in comment----------

Ok, I think I found another type checking error. The following line returns false because you are checking a float against an int:

```
    $result = ceil($num / getInc($num)) * getInc($num);
    if ($result === $num) {
```

`$result` is a always a float because `ceil()` returns a result of type float. When you do the strict comparison `===` and `$num` happens to be an integer, it returns false because even though they might be the same value, they are not identical types. That causes the integer input of 10 to act strangely.

```
(10 === 10.0) // false in php because int !== float
```

However if you [use the  equals comparison](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) instead `==` it will probably come out ok. I wouldn't be surprised if there are some other type checking errors, I just didn't go through each function.

It seems like the big difference you are running up against is because of the variable types in JavaScript are different from the variable types in PHP. [JavaScript only has the notion of type number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#number_type) which are all stored as floating point numbers but it doesn't distinguish between integers and floats. However [PHP has both floats and integers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.intro.php). When you do strict comparison, you need to make sure not only the value is equal but the type is too.

Hope this helps you work through any other bugs in the code.

Comment: Thank you so much Tyler, helped a lot! Unfortunately the math  seems very different from JS, since the vast majority of the results are wrong for getInc(), inc(), getDec() and dec()... I am very confused with how PHP does the math

Comment: Do you have some test numbers that I can run through each function to see where the diff is? When I use `inc(2)` or `dec(2)` they both work the same. But I'm not sure what number set you are trying to test.

Comment: The two functions are supposed to accept all numbers. They first pass through getInc or getDec to determine the incrementation, and they get incremented or decremented. From what I can understand so far, the ```%```seems to act different than in JS, in the line ```if ((log10($abs) % 1 === 0) && ($num < 0)) { return $num / 10;  }``` the condition ```(log10($abs) % 1 === 0)```seems to be always true. The point of this line is to change the interval for values likes 1, 10, -1, -0.1 etc. I think the math "errors" are coming from this first step.

Comment: I also added an edited PHP code in the original post.

Comment: I just updated my answer above. It seems like you are running up against type checking errors because data types in PHP are different than data types in JS. `log10($abs) % 1` will always return an integer. First of all `log10()` returns a float but when you use `%` it casts it to integer. so if there is no remainder, that line always returns true.